# Change embossing in bootstrap navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tried a lot of things to get rid of the embossing on the navbar and it's not working, I think I need someone that knows more about customizing bootstrap to take a look at this.

[image]

I'm trying to make the stuff pointed out (green arrows) and the menu selection transparent so my background shows and the navbar is integrated into the site better (flat) I'm stuck on this and can't figure it out.

Comment: can't say much. must be box shadow. Hit `F12` or right click inspect element. you can always use the browser dev tools to see what styles are being applied.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of inspection looking for box_shadow I found the problem

```
.navbar-default {
    box-shadow: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```